# HTML form method POST gets changed to GET but very rarely, and only on clicked link

Tags: html, forms, post, get

Apologies if this is not done correctly, my first question and extremely strange.  I have a simple form with some hidden inputs that get passed to a CGI on submit.  An example:

'''

```
  <input type="hidden" NAME="account" VALUE="myaccount" />
  <input type="hidden" NAME="xvalue" VALUE="newval" />
  <input type="hidden" name="NAME" id="NAME" value="yourname" />
  <input type="hidden" name="USER_DATA" value="computer" />

  <input name="PASSWORD" id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" value="" /><br>
  <input type="submit" formmethod="post" value="Start" />

</form>
```

'''

This works 99.9% of the time. I have a user that when they click on a link in a gmail account, with Firefox as the default browser, they hit an index page with the above form.  When they attempt to submit the form, the POST method returns as GET on the server side.  I've tested this by pointing the action= to a php page that echos all variables returned.  When I print $_server[request_method] in php the request_method returns GET, so the POST variables are blank. I need the POST variable to be accurate for the CGI to work properly.  To make this even more odd, it only happens on his Android phone, using gmail email client and clicking on the link, with FF as the default browser.  My user has tested several combinations of email clients and browsers, and this is the only combination when the problem happens.  Works fine if the link is copied and pasted, or typed in browser, and the index page is hit.  We have another user who reported the same issue on an iPhone, unknown email client and browser.

I and my colleagues have tested on Android phones, gmail client, Firefox 68 (same as client) with a forwarded link that does not work on client phone.  We've tested on as many devices and operating systems that we have, and we cannot recreate the issue, including on client server and an internal server.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I thought I had put the open form tag, but maybe not? '''     <form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/mycgi/mycgi.cgi" autocomplete="off"> '''